# JPG colour changes in PIL and MS Edge

Tags: python-imaging-library, microsoft-edge

I have a jpg that appear different after passing through PIL. The blue is supposed to be Process Cyan, and the yellow is supposed to be Process Yellow.

The same colour change happens if I open the JPG in MS Edge.

Would anyone know why the colour changes? I vaguely know that jpg is already supposed to be RGB, and PIL also works natively in RGB.

```
from PIL import Image
Logo_link = 'C:/Data/namecard/logo.jpg'
logo = Image.open(Logo_link)
logo.show()
```

[image: Actual JPG as opened in Windows 10 Photos]

[image: After passing through PIL / Or the same JPG opened in Microsoft Edge]

Comment: You say you have a JPEG but there appear to be 2 PNG images?

Comment: I screenshot so that I can reproduce the problem visually here, it hence it appears as png.

Comment: My guess would be that your original JPEG contains an ICC profile that is not being respected. You should be able to check with **ImageMagick** using `magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE.JPG`

Comment: Does this problem occur in Chrome? You can try the solutions in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041044/convert-jpg-from-adobergb-to-srgb-using-pil) to check if it works.